# Reference request on complex projective algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, projective-space

I am looking for a reference on complex algebraic projective geometry.
Specifically, I would like to become more acquainted with notions like the dimension and the degree of a projective algebraic set, intersection theory (Bézout's theorem), etc. For example:

Let $V,W$ be algebraic hypersurfaces of a complex projective space, and assume that $V \subset W$. Assume moreover that $V=\{P=0\}$ and $W=\{Q=0\}$, where $P,Q$ are homogenous polynomials, and $\mathrm{deg} P \geq \mathrm{deg} Q$.

I can see that this should imply $V=W$. However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I would like to see this kind of things treated systematically, if possible without using too much machinery (like schemes).

Comment: Maybe Mumford's _Algebraic Geometry I: Complex Projective Varieties_ would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of references. Let me cite a few from which I've learnt the basics

Griffihs & Harris - Principles of Algebraic Geometry

Huybrechts - Complex Geometry, An introduction

Shafarevich - Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, 2

Fulton - Algebraic Curves

Hartshorne - Algebraic Geometry

Demailly - Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry

Some of these are far from discuss only the basics or only the complex case but they cover all that I think you'll need for a while.

Comment: thanks ! any one that you would recommend specifically?

Comment: Fulton for the first steps. Then Shafarevich and Huybrechts (if you want a differential geometry approach).

Comment: great, thanks !

Comment: It would help if you study something about Several Complex Variables and Riemann Surfaces.

Comment: I do have a background in riemann surfaces and teichmüller theory, and a little bit of SVC. my main problem is that I am very ignorant in algebra

Comment: A course in Commutative Algebra would be very useful, even necessary before studying schemes.

For now think that every algebra is of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ to get the geometric feeling...

Answer (score 1):

Intersect with a copy of an affine space, so now $P, Q$ are inhomogeneous polynomials $p, q$, but choose the copy of affine space so that $p, q$ continue to have the same degrees as $P, Q$. If $V \subseteq W$, then the polynomial $q$ vanishes on $V$, so by the [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) some power of $q$ lies in the ideal $(p)$ generated by $p$.

At this point you need some additional hypothesis on $p$ to rule out annoying possibilities like $p = x^2, q = xy$. Let me assume that $p$ is irreducible. Then $p$ divides $q$, so $q$ is a scalar multiple of $q$ and $V = W$ as desired.

Comment: thanks, but I included this specific question as an example of the kind of questions I would like to be more familiar with. do you have any book to suggest to that effect?